# in swift, how to use a unique instance of a struct to implement a tableView?

Tags: swift, uitableview, struct

i have an instance of this struct:

```
class AlimentObjectTronque {

    var aRetinol : Float = 0
    var aBetacarotene : Float = 0
    var vitamineC : Float = 0
    var vitamineB1 : Float = 0
    var calcium : Float = 0
    var omega3 : Float = 0

    
    init(aRetinol: Float, aBetacarotene: Float, vitamineC: Float, vitamineB1: Float, calcium: Float, omega3: Float) {
        
        self.aRetinol = aRetinol
        self.aBetacarotene = aBetacarotene
        self.vitamineC = vitamineC
        self.vitamineB1 = vitamineB1
        self.calcium = calcium
        self.omega3 = omega3
    }
    
    convenience init() {
        self.init(aRetinol: 0, aBetacarotene: 0, vitamineC: 0, vitamineB1: 0, calcium: 0, omega3: 0)
    }

}
```

and i need to put in each line of a tableView, a propertie of the instance of this struct.

```
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
            return // ????
        }
        
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellFind", for: indexPath) as? AlimentToAddCell else {
                return UITableViewCell() }
            // ????
            
            return cell
        }
```

i need to know how to put in each line of the tableview, a propertie of the instance.

Comment: `numberOfRowsInSection`: return 6, because 1 for each properties. On the `cellForRowAt`, do a `switch indexPath.row {} `, and according to it, set the `cell.textLabel.text` to `"\(myStruct.aRetinol)"` or the corresponding one.

Comment: Fist of all this is a `class` not a `struct`. It _could_ be a struct and save you all the initialization code (it would be generated automatically for you). Finally, all you need after that is some sort of list (array, set etc) of these objects (just realized that you said 'properties' - still a valid suggestion) in order to drive your tableview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the properties of **one** instance in a table view use **static** cells

- In Interface Builder choose `Static Cells` in Content of the Attributes Inspector of the table view.
- Drag six cells into the canvas
- In the controller create six `UILabel` outlets and connect them to the text label of the cells respectively for example

  ```
  @IBOutlet var aRetinolLabel : UILabel!
  @IBOutlet var aBetacaroteneLabel : UILabel!
  ...
  ```
- Use a struct rather than a class and delete all initializers, you get the memberwise initializer for free

  ```
  struct AlimentObjectTronque {
      var aRetinol : Float
      var aBetacarotene : Float
      var vitamineC : Float
      var vitamineB1 : Float
      var calcium : Float
      var omega3 : Float
  }
  ```
- Delete also the conformance to `UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` and the related methods
- Assign the values to the labels directly.

  ```
  let alimentObject = AlimentObjectTronque(aRetinol: 2.0, aBetacarotene: 3.0...
  aRetinolLabel.text = String(alimentObject.aRetinol)
  aBetacarotene.text = String(alimentObject.aBetacarotene)
  ...
  ```

Comment: could you help me please for a problem with refactoring? here is the link [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63887294/inswift-how-to-change-values-of-an-array-composed-by-a-struct-objects)

Comment: Sorry, I don’t understand the question either.

Comment: here is the link to it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63902710/in-swift-how-to-implement-a-function-that-take-in-parametre-the-name-of-a-prope)